# Let $\ln X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$ and $X,Y$ i.i.d. What is the distribution of $Z=XY$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convolution

Let $\ln X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$ and $X,Y$ i.i.d. 
What is the distribution of $Z=XY$?

My attempt: $$P(Z\le z)=P(XY\le z)=P(\ln(XY)\le \ln(z))=P(\ln(X)+\ln(Y)\le \ln(z))$$

We need the convolution, since $\ln X $ and $\ln Y$ are independent we get, $$\int_0^{\ln(z)} f_{\ln(X)}\circledast f_{\ln(Y)}=\int_0^{\ln(z)}e^{-y}e^{-x+y}\,dy=e^{-x}ln(z),$$ i.e. $e^{-x}\ln(z)$ is the density of $XY$

Comment: How did $1-e^{-e^{w}}$ become $1-e^{-ew}$? $\ln (X)$ and $\ln (Y)$ are not exponentially distributed.

Comment: you mean X and Y are not exponential distributed?

Comment: You are saying that $W=\ln X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $e$. I am saying that this is not true. $e^{-e^{w}}$ stands for $e^{-u}$ where $u=e^{w}$. It is different from $(e^{-e})^{w}$.

Comment: yes I see. that is actaully nonsense what I did. $W\sim exp (1)$. So $ ln (X)+ln(Y) \sim exp (2) $

Comment: You cannot use the semi-group property of exponential distribution. You have to do some more computations to find the distribution of the sum $\ln X+\ln Y$. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparantly $X$ is a positive rv (if not then $\ln X$ would not be well defined).

So you can start with
$$\ln Z=\ln XY=\ln X+\ln Y=R+S$$

Now let's find the distribution of $R+S$ where $R,S$ are iid with $\mathsf{Exp}(1)$-distribution.

For $x>0$ we find:
\begin{align}
P(R+S>x)
& =\int_0^{\infty} P(R+S>x\mid S=s)e^{-s}ds
=\int_0^{\infty} P(R>x-s)e^{-s}ds \\
& =\int_0^xe^{s-x}e^{-s}ds+\int_x^{\infty}e^{-s}ds
= e^{-x}(1+x)
\end{align}

Then for $z>1$ $$P(Z>z)=P(\ln Z>\ln z)=P(R+S>\ln z)=e^{-\ln z}(1+\ln z)=\frac{1+\ln z}{z}$$

This leads to $F_Z(z)=1-\frac{1+\ln z}{z}$ for $z>1$ and $F_Z(z)=0$ for $z\leq1$.

---

It seems that you think that $R+S$ has exponential distribution with rate $2$.

That however is the case for $\min(R,S)$ as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables).

Comment: Why does the upper bound of integration change from $\infty$ to $x$?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Denoting the integrand as $h(s)$ the integral $\int_0^{\infty}h(s)ds$ is written as sum $\int_0^{x}h(s)ds+\int_x^{\infty}h(s)ds$. In the first term the integrand gets shape $e^{-x}$, in second term it gets shape $e^{-s}$.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need the assumption in the first sentence because since $\ln(X) \sim $Exp$(1)$ we know that $\ln(X) \ge 0$ almost surely implying $X \ge 1$ almost surely, right?

Comment: In the first sentence no assumption is made, but an observation. In your calculation of $P(\ln(XY)\leq x)$ the third expression is illegal because $P(Y=y)=0$. The fourth expression is okay but in the fifth there are two mistakes: $P(\ln X+\ln Y\leq x\mid Y=y)=P(\ln X\leq x-\ln y)$ (and not  $P(\ln X\leq x-y)$) and $f_Y(y)\neq e^{-y}$. Remember that $\ln Y$ has exponential distribution (not $Y$). I stop commenting now. If things are not clear yet then ask it in a question.

Comment: It might be useful to point out that the conditional probability used here is the advanced measure theoretic concept of [regular conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability) and not the standard condition probability we are used to since by the standard definition $P(R + S > s \mid S =s) \le P(S = s) = 0$ because $S$ is continuously distributed.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik What makes you state that $P(R+S>s\mid S=s)\leq P(S=s)$?

Comment: I assumed you were using the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$ I know and then used $A \cap B \subset B$. In this definition $\P(B) = 0$, which makes the fraction ill-defined, so nothing checks out anyway.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik You will agree with me that we do not have $P(A\mid B)\leq P(B)$ in general, right?

Comment: Yes of course..

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution using convolution:
Let $\overline{X} := \ln(X)$ and $\overline{Y}$ analogously.
We can now calculate the PDF of $\ln(XY) = \overline{X} + \overline{Y}$ using convolution:
For $x \ge 0$ we have
$$
f_{\ln(XY)}(x)
= f_{\overline{X}} \ast f_{\overline{Y}}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{\overline{X}}(y) f_{\overline{Y}}(x - y) \ \text{d}y
= \int_{0}^{x} e^{-y} e^{y - x}  \ \text{d}y
= \int_{0}^{x} e^{-x}  \ \text{d}y
= x e^{x}
$$ 
and $f_{\ln(XY)}(x) = 0$ otherwise.
Therefore, for $x \ge 0$ we have
$$
P(\ln(XY) \le x)
= \int_{-\infty}^{x}f_{\ln(XY)}(y)\ \text{d}y
= \int_{0}^{x} y e^{-y} \ \text{d}y
= 1 - e^{-x}(x + 1).
$$
For $z \ge 1$ this implies
$$
P(XY \le z)
= 1 - \frac{1 + \ln(z)}{z}
.
$$
and $P(XY \le z) = 0$ for $z \le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way without using the functional equation of the logarithm and instead deriving the PDF of $X$ directly.

Since $\ln(X) \sim$Exp$(1)$, for all $k \ge 0$ we have
\begin{equation*}
 \mathbb{P}(X \le e^k)
 = \mathbb{P}(\ln(X) \le k)
 = 1 - e^{-k}
\end{equation*}
By substitution one obtains
\begin{equation*}
 \mathbb{P}(X \le a)
 = 1 - \frac{1}{a}.
\end{equation*}
for all $a \ge 1$. 
We can now obtain the density function by calculating the derivative: $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Now, for $z \ge 1$ we have 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(XY \le z)
& = \int_{1}^{\infty} 1_{(-\infty,z]}(x,y) \ \text{d}\mathbb{P}(x,y)
= \int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} 1_{\left(1, \frac{z}{y}\right)}(x) \ \text{d}\mathbb{P}_{X} \ \text{d}\mathbb{P}_{Y} \\
& = \int_{1}^{z} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} 1_{\left(1, \frac{z}{y}\right)}(x) \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{1}{y^2} \ \text{d}x \ \text{d}y \\ 
& = \int_{1}^{z} \frac{1}{y^2} \left[ \int_{1}^{\frac{z}{y}} \frac{1}{x^2} \ \text{d}x \right] \text{d}y \\
& = \int_{1}^{z} \frac{1}{y^2} \left(1 - \frac{y}{z}\right) \text{d}y
= 1 - \frac{1 + \ln(z)}{z}.
\end{align*}

*Note: Yet another way to this by realising that the sum of exponential distributed random variables is gamma distributed, can be found on this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273969/alternative-approach-to-x-y-i-i-d-lnx-simexp1-find-cdf-of-xy/3276411#3276411).*

Comment: Just a remark: in exponential cases I would plead for working not on CDF $F$ but on $P(X>x)=1-F_X(x)$. Not essential, but just a bit more pleasant to work with. The nasty $1-e^{-x}\cdots$ makes place for the more comfortable $e^{-x}$.