# Alternative Approach to: $X,Y$ i.i.d, $\ln(X) \sim$Exp$(1)$. Find CDF of $XY$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

This question was already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2921211/let-ln-x-sim-operatornameexp1-and-x-y-i-i-d-what-is-the-distribution) (I've also added an approach using $\ln(XY) = \ln(X) + \ln(Y)$ there) but I am asking this question to clear some things up about the other answer and ask whether my alternative albeit similar approach is correct or how to fix it.

**Question**
First, @drhab states that  “Apparently $X$ is a positive rv (if not then $\ln(X)$ would not be well defined).”
But if $\ln(X) \sim$Exp$(1)$, this implies that $\ln(X) \ge 0$ almost surely and therefore $X \ge 1$ almost surely, which suffices to show that $\ln(X)$ is well defined, right?

**Approach**
Since $\ln(X) \sim$Exp$(1)$, for all $k \ge 0$ we have
\begin{equation*}
 \mathbb{P}(X \le e^k)
 = \mathbb{P}(\ln(X) \le k)
 = 1 - e^{-k}
\end{equation*}
By substitution I obtained
\begin{equation*}
 \mathbb{P}(X \le a)
 = 1 - \frac{1}{a}.
\end{equation*}
for all $a \ge 1$. 
We can now obtain the density function by calculating the derivative: $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Now, for $z \ge 1$ we have 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(XY \le z)
& = \int_{1}^{\infty} 1_{(-\infty,z]}(x,y) \ \text{d}\mathbb{P}(x,y)
= \int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} 1_{\left(1, \frac{z}{y}\right)}(x) \ \text{d}\mathbb{P}_{X} \ \text{d}\mathbb{P}_{Y} \\
& = \int_{1}^{z} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} 1_{\left(1, \frac{z}{y}\right)}(x) \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{1}{y^2} \ \text{d}x \ \text{d}y \\ 
& = \int_{1}^{z} \frac{1}{y^2} \left[ \int_{1}^{\frac{z}{y}} \frac{1}{x^2} \ \text{d}x \right] \text{d}y \\
& = \int_{1}^{z} \frac{1}{y^2} \left(1 - \frac{y}{z}\right) \text{d}y
= 1 - \frac{1 + \ln(z)}{z}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I think you've messed up the limits a bit. The integral over $Y$ has to be from $1$ to $\infty$, not over $\mathbb{R}_+$. Further, the X cdf is $0$ if $z/y < 1.$ So the final integral should read $$ \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{y^2} (1- y/z) \mathbf{1}\{ z/y \ge 1\} \,\mathrm{d}y = \int_1^z \frac{1}{y^2} (1-y/z) \,\mathrm{d}y .$$

Comment: BTW - an alternate approach would be to note that $\ln(XY) = \ln X + \ln Y$ is a sum of two independent exponential RVs, and it's law is $\Gamma(2,1)$. Then you can exponentiate this as you did in the Q. to figure out the law of $XY$.

Comment: I edited the question to include that I have already added an answer to the linked question using this functional equation of the logarithm and convolution of PDFs but I am also interested in your solution using the Gamma distribution,if I understand correctly? Could you please elaborate on that and include which definition of the gamma distribution you are working with? Wikipedia cites two.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 since your correcting leads to the correct result, I would encourage you formulating your comments as an answer :)

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I have now edited to correct my calculation. Is it correct now? I am also worried about notation, i.e. all the d$\mathbb{P}$, d$\mathbb{P}_X$ floating around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stochasticboy321 correctly pointed out, the mistake I made was with the upper bound of my integral.

As he mentioned as well, one could also notice that the sum $\ln(XY) = \ln(X) + \ln(Y)$ of two exponentially distributed random variables [is $\Gamma(2,1)$-distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationships_among_probability_distributions#Sum_of_variables), i.e. the CDF of $\ln(Z)$ is
$$
e^{-1x} \sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{(1x)^k}{k!}
= 1 -e^{-x} x - e^{-x}
$$
This means for $z \ge 1$
$$
\mathbb{P}(Z \le e^z)
= \mathbb{P}(\ln(Z) \le z)
= 1 - \frac{z + 1}{e^{z}}
\implies \mathbb{P}(Z \le z) = 1 - \frac{\ln(z) + 1}{z} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

To address your first question, I would phrase the problem in a more precise way to make it clear everything is well-defined. Let $Z,Z'$ be iid random variables such that $$\mathbb P(Z>t)=e^{-t},\quad \forall t\geq 0.\qquad (1)$$  Let $X=e^Z$ and let $Y=e^{Z'}$. (There is no question that everything is well-defined in this formulation, and that it is equivalent to yours.)

Translating your calculations into a more probabilistic language,
$$
\mathbb P(XY\leq z\mid Y)=\mathbb P\bigl(X\leq \frac{z}{Y}\mid Y\bigr)=\bigl(1-\frac{Y}{z}\bigr)1_{Y\leq z},
$$
where we have applied $(1)$ with $e^t=z/Y$ in the last equality. Then,
$$
\mathbb P(XY\leq z)=\mathbb E\bigl(1-\frac{Y}{z};Y\leq z\bigr).
$$
Let me now point out a slightly different way of performing this last integral, which perhaps makes it more transparent where the terms are coming from.
$$
\mathbb E\bigl(1-\frac{Y}{z};Y\leq z\bigr)=\mathbb E\bigl(1-\frac{e^{Z}}{z};Z\leq \log z\bigr)=\int_0^{\log z}(1-\frac{e^x}{z})\cdot (e^{-x} dx).$$
Now the integrand equals $e^{-x}-1/z$. Integrating the first term gives $1-1/z$, and integrating the second gives $$-\frac{\log z}{z},$$
which yields the desired expression.

Comment: I am taking an introductory course on probability theory and unfortunately don't know what $\mathbb{E}( \cdot ; \cdot)$. Secondly: what does $\mathbb{P}(XY \le z \mid Y$ mean? I know conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$ for events $A$ and $B$ but not for random variables.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb E(X; A)$ is simply a common notation for $\mathbb E(X1_A)$, it was especially common in classical textbooks when it was less convenient to typeset subscripts (especially for complicated events). Conditional probability involving a random variable is a special case of conditional expectation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation where the object whose expectation we are taking is an indicator random variable.